# Need to get state data from Authentication Cubit inside another Cubit. In essence, I need to read the state

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc, cubit

Note: I've seen similar questions all over Stackoverflow, but none of them exactly answer this.

**Context:**

I have an authentication cubit that has a variety of user states:

```
/// User exists, includes user's access and refresh tokens.
class User extends AuthenticationState {
  final Tokens? tokens;
  final bool justRegistered;
  final bool tokensAvailable;

  User({
    required this.tokens,
    this.justRegistered = false,
    this.tokensAvailable = true,
  });

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [tokens, justRegistered, tokensAvailable];
}

/// No authenticated user exists.
class NoUser extends AuthenticationState {}

/// User is currently being registered or signed in.
class UserLoading extends AuthenticationState {}
```

**Problem:**

I have a Posts Cubit that needs to manage API calls and pass in the current user's access token to them in order to work. However, this access token is only stored inside the Authentication Cubit's state (in the `User` state, inside the `tokens` variable).

Is there a (good practice) way to get this token from the Authentication Cubit's User state inside the Post Cubit so I can use it to send API requests that require tokens for authentication to return posts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class something like API Provider and authenticateService, pass and use in your Cubit to call API :

**For example:**

```
 Future<Response<dynamic>> _callAndRetryDelete(
    String url, {
    int validStatus,
    int retries,
  }) async =>
      retry(
        () async {
          final Map<String, String> authHeaders = await _authenticationService.getAuthHeaders;
          if (authHeaders == null) {
            throw ApiError('Could not get authorization', endpoint: url, method: HTTPMethod.Delete);
          }
          _client.options = _options(success: validStatus, authHeaders: authHeaders);
          try {
            return await _client.delete(url);
          } on DioError catch (error) {
            final String message = _error(error);
            throw ApiError(message, endpoint: url, method: HTTPMethod.Delete);
          }
        },
        maxAttempts: retries,
      );
```

**AuthenticaionService.class**

```
Future<void> _doLogin(Map<String, dynamic> params) async {

  final Response<Map<String, dynamic>> response =
      await _handler.post(_loginEndpoint, body: params, 
           validStatus: 200);

  final Map<String, String> res =
      response?.data?.map((String key, dynamic value) => MapEntry<String, String>(key, value.toString()));

  final Authentication authentication = Authentication.parse(res);
  await _parseAndStore(authentication);
  return authentication;}
```

**AuthCubit:**

```
Future<void> signIn() async => cubitAction(
action: () async {
  emit(AuthenticationLoading());
  await _authenticationService.signIn(payload);
  emit(AuthenticationDone);
}
```

);

Comment: How would this work with the single source of truth principle? If I have an _authenticationService that also has the token values alongside the Authentication Cubit User state, won't that be bad because I'd have to update both when they change?

Comment: I am suggesting to use authenticationService to authenticate and save token in this class only, and use object of this class in your cubit/api provider class to get saved accessToken,

Comment: So _authenticationService would be a separate utility class that would store the token values, to be provided to my authentication cubit and API cubit? The authentication cubit would also then update this _authenticationService class? Where would I put this service class?